# Centos docker container crashes with 6 Segmentation fault - where's the core dump

Tags: docker, centos, segmentation-fault, centos7, coredump

running a Centos 7.1.1503 docker container, when adding a few lines of code (node.js) it crashes with the error:

```
/bin/sh: line 1:     6 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) node --inspect server.js
```

the file `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` contains the following:

```
|/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp %s %c %p %u %g %t e
```

There's no /var/spool/abrt directory within the container. The /var/spool/abrt directory on the server running the containers doesn't get anything.
I can't change the /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern to point to another directory/program because of the read-only fs thing. Can't run the container in privileged, either :-(

I've read through tonnes of docker/stackexchange and other docs and can't figure out where/how to get the core dump?

In the olden days I'd play with the settings and wreck a replica of the machine, but this is a production container and I'm very limited in what I can do and when/how many times I can crash it :-(

Host is RHEL 7.1, docker version is 1.7

EDIT: On my laptop, running the same container (with docker 1.12 though), I sometimes get core dumps **on the host** /var/spool/abrt by running `sleep 60 &` **in the container, then running (still in the container) `kill -ABRT <pid of the sleep 60>`** . By "sometimes" I mean that trying again doesn't always work... I'm not sure why, but about 2 out of 3 tries succeed. I figure this might have to do with a privileged run or something..? I run the container with `docker run -it centos bash`. If I can understand this I might replicate this behavior in the production env.

Comment: Are you able to execute docker inspect on the host machine? I can provide instructions to access the container filesystem after its crash, if it's the case.

Comment: Hi @David Gonzalez, I can provide the inspect but am more interested in understanding if I can expect anything in \var\spool\abrt (the directory doesn't exist and I can't see any indication of the ABRT daemon running, or any abrt* commands available in the container)

Comment: If a command *inside* a docker container dies with a seg fault, any core dump is going to be generated *inside* the docker container filesystem, not on your host.

Comment: @larsks , you're right but some configs set the host direcctory as the one to out core dumps to them. In a non production environment (my laptop..) I've managed to do sleep 60 & and then kill -ABRT <pid> inside a container, and get the dump on the host's /var/spool/abrt dir

Comment: Hi @David Gonzalez , not sure how to forward the inspect output to you (it's a bit sensitive so I'd rather refrain from posting it to the wide world). Can we chat or email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up skipping the abrt and changing the core_pattern file to out to a directory on the host. Here's my two bytes on getting a core dump out of a crashing docker instance:

On the host:

```
docker run --privileged -it -v /tmp:/core image-name bash
```

(you can do this with docker exec, but my machine didn't have the flags available to exec)

--privileged = required to be able to edit the /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern file

-v = to mount the /tmp directory of the host in a /core directory in the container

In the instance:

set the location of the core dumps to /core (which is a mount of the /tmp dir in the host machine):

```
echo "/core/core-%e-%s-%u-%g-%p-%t" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

test it:

```
sleep 60 &  
kill -SEGV <pid of that sleep process>
```

Should be able to see a core file in the /tmp dir on the host. When my instance crashed, I finally got the dump in the host machine.

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following command to get a report of the paths of the upper layer of the filesystem of all the centos containers you may have launched:

`docker ps -a | grep centos | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker inspect | grep UpperDir | cut -d\" -f4`

Bear in mind that you will have to become sudo to be able to access them (run `sudo su` before cd'ing)

The command above does the following:

1. Get a report of all the containers existing in your host
2. Select only the ones that have centos in their line
3. Get the first row of that report (container ID)
4. Get the inspect of every one of those containers
5. Look for the UpperDir parameter (upper layer of your container filesystem, and the one you tinkered with when your process crashed)
6. Cut the UpperDir string for improved presentation

After that, you are on your own. I am afraid I am of no help with the crash itself. But if you are still doubtful, write me some lines and I'll do my best ot help.

I hope this helps you!